# How to get parent record when deeply nest property in arrays equal value?

Tags: java, subquery, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I need to retrieve a parent object based on two properties of deeply nested properties. I am using Spring Data MongoDB with QueryDSL. I know I need to do a subquery, but I have been unable to put one together.

```
entity.benefitList.benefits.benefitCode = DisplayFancy
entity.benefitList.benefits.benefitValueList.benefitValues.value = Yes
```

Here is the entity setup:

```
entity = {
    benefitList: {
        benefits: [
            benefitCode: <code>
            benefitValueList: {
                benefitValues: [
                  value: <value>
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I set up a subquery to get both criteria. I want to make sure to get an entity where the benefits has an object.benefitCode with a certain DisplayFancy and that object having a benefitValueList having a benefitValue where the value is Yes